# Observable in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a code for example :

```
    getData(){
_someservice.somefunction(this.filterArray).subscribe(data=>this.data=data}).catch();
    }
```

Now for My service:

```
    export class someService{
    somefunction(filter:any){
        return http.get("https:...... /?parameter="+filter).map(this.extractData).catch();
    }
}
```

When i give different FilterArray , i still get Old FilterArray Data instead of new FilterArray Data from url.
Like For example : I have currently FilterArray as ["A","B"], and i get some data from Url . Now i change FilterArray to ["C","D"], i still receive ["A","B"] data from url .

Edit:
I call in getData() whenever FilterArray is changed. i.e

```
    <div>
<select>
<option *ngFor="let x of filterArray" (click)="getData()">{{x}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

What should i do ? Do i have to unsubscribe every-time the filterArray is changed ?

Comment: How do you use `getData()`? And why do you wrap `somefunction` with `getData` ?  Where do you change `filterArray`? Please provide some more code.

Comment: Thanks for he reply . I have added additional code .

Comment: this.filterArray or this.data? which one is correct in your case?

Comment: @micronyks i've changed it. I'm sorry i missed that part

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) apply given function and change/alter into new emitted value. Looks like var `this.extractData` inside `map` always return same value.